# Root path specification no longer resolves to subdomain

Tags: path, subdomain

I use a subdomain that I use for my development site, with the tld being production. I password protect the subdomain and instruct robots not to traverse etc. It has worked for 9 years. I came in after not updating my website for the past year, and found that the "root" path specification (e.g. "/subdir/file.html") now no longer resolves to root of the subdomain, but to the tld.

e.g. I go to "mysubdomain.mysite.com". I notice that the address bar shows mysite.com/mysubdomain/index.html" (seems wrong). Then, clicking a link coded as "/subdir/file.html" goes to mysite.com/filex.html rather than mysubdomain.mysite.com/filex.html.

So, I think maybe there is a problem at the hosting site, maybe something I should modify in cpanel, but not sure.

Comment: Are you able to see the sub domain entry in cPanel --> Sub domains section? If no, please add it again and it should work.

Comment: Yes, I can see it. It is set to the other, no forwarding.